# In Kubernetes, how can I wait for updated code to be deployed in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a working Kubernetes cluster hosted in the Google Kubernetes Engine. I can apply new code to the cluster by building a Docker image with the new code, pushing the image (with a new tag) to the Google Container Registry, and then `kubectl apply`-ing an updated manifest (using the new tag) to the cluster.

I have a manual step (specifically, `rails db:migrate` to apply new migrations to the database) that I want to happen once the new code has been deployed. I can execute this command just fine as a `kubectl exec` command. But there's a problem: I need to run it against the new image, not the old image. Running it against the old image will succeed, in the sense that the exit code will be 0, but it will not apply the new migrations, which are only present in the new image.

My question: **How can I wait for new code to be live in a cluster before I run a `kubectl exec` command against it?**

Note that I can't do a `kubectl run` using the new image, because the container by itself can't access the database; it needs the "sidecar" CloudSQL proxy container running in the same pod.

One more constraint: I need to do this in a scripting environment (e.g. bash), so repeatedly running a command and examining the output manually isn't an option. Doing an automatic, scripted loop until some condition is met does count as a solution, but I'd really prefer something that doesn't require me to poll in my script.

A `sleep` of some duration could sort of solve this problem, but there are problems with that approach:

- The sleep time might not be long enough for everything to finish (and the time that takes is variable and difficult to predict).
- If I sleep longer than I need to, the Rails app will refuse to work because it will recognize that there are database migrations that haven't been applied—which should be considered downtime for the app.

Comment: Have a look at [helm](https://helm.sh/). Through it you can deploy connected container infrastructure like one package. It also has a `--wait` option.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem correctly then I think [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) will solve your problem fairly well. Init containers allow you to do certain tasks before a pod is started.

So in your case, something to tunes of the following will serve the purpose (Code copied from the link above):

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: rails-app
  labels:
    app: myapp
  annotations:
    pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[
        {
            "name": "init-myservice",
            "image": "new-image",
            "command": ["sh", "-c", "rails db:migrate"]
        }
    ]'
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-rails-app
    image: new-image`

Let's run over how this will work:

- You will build and push the new image of the app to registry. You will have to modify the pod definition to have init containers as above of course.
- You will apply the new version via kubectl to deployment
- The init container uses same image as that your app uses, but is used only for the execution of rails DB migration.
- After that actual app starts.

Even if you have N replicas of the the pod with a `deployment` or `replication controller` object - then the migration might run N times (Once for each pod). It is not intended or best path but wont have any issues as the first pod that comes up would have done migration anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although I'm not sure whether init containers will work, because of the need for a sidecar container running in the same pod as the container running the migrations. I don't think there's a way to do that with init containers, although I would love for you to prove me wrong!

Comment: I am sorry but can you please explain the need for sidecar container? Of course, init containers won't stay after execution but you can still have a separate sidecar anyway.

Comment: Sure. The sidecar container is a requirement to use CloudSQL in the Google Cloud Platform. For some reason I don't understand, they want you to use a proxy to tunnel to the database rather than connecting directly. Could you clarify your second sentence? Are you saying that the sidecar can be active and available even while the init container runs the database migration?

Comment: @JeffTerrellPh.D. So Init container will finish the execution after which all containers in the pod will be started, so it should work in your case IMHO

Comment: I think you just explained why that approach will _not_ work. If the sidecar container doesn't start until after the init container has finished, then the sidecar won't be available when the init container is trying to migrate the database.